# Magento 2: How to use translation to change the adminhtml button text?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, localisation, inline-translations

I want to change the invoice button name on the sales order, how to do that using  translation (**i18n**)

[image]

For testing I tried to change the translation in this path `/vendor/magento/module-sales/i18n/en_US.csv` and then changed the admin setting but that not worked

```
admin > Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Translate Inline > Enabled for Storefront as YES
```

[image]

Is there any other way to override the adminhtml translation ?

Comment: Which you marked in image it's "Invoice" and in csv It's "Invoices".

Comment: actually i have just given example, i tried with "Send Email" which is present in the csv, but for that it not worked

Comment: also can you let me know how to override this path /vendor/magento/module-sales/i18n/en_US.csv  as it is core

Comment: Did you do upgrade deploy after change in csv? It's working from my end after upgrade deploy.

Comment: ok, i will try again..can you suggest how to override the i18n folder, the path where i place the translation csv

Comment: Just Copy this file vendor\magento\module-fedex\i18n\en_US.csv and paste it to any of your extension app\code\vendor\module\i18n
is this correct way ?

Comment: Yes. It's correct way. I added both way in answer. Let me know if it's not work.

Comment: ok, will update you soon, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override translation csv file using this way :

> app/design/{AreaName}/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv

or You can follow this 2nd way also

Just Copy this file `vendor\magento\module-sales\i18n\en_US.csv` and paste it to any of your extension `app\code\vendor\module\i18n`

After, Process Upgrade and Deploy step and check it.

Comment: Just Copy this file vendor\magento\module-sales\i18n\en_US.csv and paste it to any of your extension app\code\vendor\module\i18n did this way, thanks

Comment: Thanks !! Happy to help !! Happy Coding :)

Comment: Happy coding :)